# Printing wide character literals in C

Tags: c, unicode, widechar

I am trying to print unicode to the terminal under linux using the `wchar_t` type defined in the `wchar.h` header. I have tried the following:

```c
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  /*
  char* direct = "\xc2\xb5";

  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", direct);
  */

  wchar_t* dir_lit = L"μ";
  wchar_t* uni_lit = L"\u03BC";
  wchar_t* hex_lit = L"\xc2\xb5";

  fwprintf(stderr,
           L"direct: %ls, unicode: %ls, hex: %ls\n",
           dir_lit,
           uni_lit,
           hex_lit);

  return 0;
}
```

and compiled it using `gcc -O0 -g -std=c11 -o main main.c`.
This produces the output `direct: m, unicode: m, hex: ?u` (based on a terminal with `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`). In hex:

```
00000000  64 69 72 65 63 74 3a 20  6d 2c 20 75 6e 69 63 6f  |direct: m, unico|
00000010  64 65 3a 20 6d 2c 20 68  65 78 3a 20 3f 75 0a     |de: m, hex: ?u.|
0000001f
```

The only way that I have managed to obtain the desired output of μ is via the code commented in above (as a `char*` consisting of hex digits).

I have also tried to print based on the `wcstombs` funtion:

```
void print_wcstombs(wchar_t* str)
{
  char buffer[100];

  wcstombs(buffer, str, sizeof(buffer));

  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", buffer);
}
```

If I call for example `print_wcstombs(dir_lit)`, then nothing is printed at all, so this approach does not seem to work at all.

I would be contend with the hex digit solution in principle, however, the length of the string is not calulated correctly (should be one, but is two bytes long), so formatting via `printf` does not work correctly.

Is there any way to handle / print unicode literals the way I intend using the `wchar_t` type?

Comment: If you add the Unicode characters directly in the format string, does it work then?

Comment: Nope, same result

Comment: And if you pipe the output through a hex-editor to see the actual hexadecimal values, do they look as you expect? If not then use the hex-editor to see the actual contents of the source file. Otherwise your terminal is misconfigured. It's one of those alternatives. :)

Comment: All looks like ASCII values...

Comment: `μ` is converted to `m`. *μ* is the Greek version of *m*. Could this be a sophisticated conversion to the terminal's character set, which likely does not include *μ*?

Comment: Well, it prints the μ correctly to the terminal  when I use the standard `printf` method commented in above. So a corresponding glyph is present in the terminal font, and the unicode character is recognized in that case...

Comment: Do not use wchar on Linux. No console/terminal can support it (per POSIX standard). Use UTF-8 and so just char. Far simpler. (and UTF-8 was created to be compatible and nice with Unix, so avoiding all problems that Microsoft has [duplicate API, but programmes still mix them]).

Comment: Well,the problem is that string formatting does not seem to work correctly: The μ is two-byte despite being *one* character, which is why stuff like `printf("%2s", "\xc2\xb5")` does not seem to work correctly, which is the reason why I used `wchar_t` in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your program as-is, I compiled and ran it to get

```
direct: ?, unicode: ?, hex: ?u
```

I then included `<locale.h>` and added a `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");` at the very beginning of the `main()` function, which, when run using a Unicode locale (`LANG=en_US.UTF-8`), produces

```
direct: μ, unicode: μ, hex: Âµ
```

(Codepoint 0xC2 is Â in Unicode and 0xB5 is µ (U+00B5 MICRO SIGN as oppposed to U+03BC GREEK SMALL LETTER MU); hence the characters seen for the 'hex' output; results might vary if using an environment that does not use Unicode for wide characters).

Basically, to output wide characters you need to set the ctype locale so the stdio system knows *how* to convert them to the multibyte ones expected by the underlying system.

---

The updated program:

```c
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

  wchar_t* dir_lit = L"μ";
  wchar_t* uni_lit = L"\u03BC";
  wchar_t* hex_lit = L"\xc2\xb5";

  fwprintf(stderr,
           L"direct: %ls, unicode: %ls, hex: %ls\n",
           dir_lit,
           uni_lit,
           hex_lit);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I wish C was one of these languages which _just works_™

Comment: It is; you just have to be very explicit about how it should work.